# Visual Studio 2010: chrono header file missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and wanted to write a simple program in C++.
But it seems like VS doesn't find the header file "chrono".
I tought installing SP1 would help, but it didn't.
There also some other header files like "thread" missing.

Does anyone know where I can get these missing files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VS2010 only has partial C++11 support. You need VS2012+.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to Mark's answer, no Visual Studio version fully supports C++11 now. Here is the complete table of features: [C++11 Features (Modern C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can also read here for getting more information [BOOST](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.chrono_hpp.conf.header_only)

Answer (score 0):

Chrono is a standard template library that has been introduced in Visual Studio 2012.
Chrono is used to manipulate time durations and time instants.

Visual Studio 2010 or even with SP1 will not support Chrono.